# How Do I Sync My Sublime Text 3 Settings Using Dropbox?

Tags: macos, settings, synchronization, dropbox, sublimetext3

I would like to sync Sublime Text 3's Settings across multiple machines using Dropbox.

How should I set this up?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I've been syncing my Sublime settings for a while between multiple locations, all running OS X. I've had some minor problems. Finally, I decided to look into it which led me to what I would consider the authoritative description of how to sync Sublime setting between multiple machines using Dropbox:

**Sublime Package Control > Docs > Syncing**
**https://sublime.wbond.net/docs/syncing**

Here is the basic summary:

> To properly sync your installed packages across different machines, you actually do not want to sync the whole `Packages/` and `Installed Packages/` folders. The reason for this is that some packages have different versions for different operating systems. By syncing the actual package contents across operating systems, you will possibly run into broken packages.
>
> The proper solution is to:
>
> 1. **[Install Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) on all machines**
> 2. **Then to sync only the `Packages/User/` folder.**
>
> This folder contains the `Package Control.sublime-settings` file, which includes a list of all installed packages. If this file is copied to another machine, the next time Sublime Text is started, Package Control will install the correct version of any missing packages.

To sync the folder, you generally move `Packages/User/` into your Dropbox and create a symlink to it from `Sublime Text 3/Packages/`. Detailed instructions for various operating systems are provided via the link above.

Comment: I run the portable version of Sublime Text 3 directly from Dropbox. Works like a charm if you use the same OS on all your machines.

Comment: @NiloVelez Good point. Will try it too instead of symlinking all that stuff.

Comment: You might have some issues if you use it simultaneously on two computers, but it shouldn't be a problem if you work alone.

Comment: Worked well for me, but I have one issue I'm unsure how to solve. I need to use a proxy for Package Control at work, but not at home. Since the Package Control settings are also synced, I have to manually add/remove the proxy setting depending on where I am. Anyone got a better solution?

Comment: The question in the previous comment is beginning to stray off topic here. The new question is "How to set up proxy for Package Control" at different locations using the same settings file". Or something like that. However, in the spirit of helping out anyway, since the settings file is a Python script perhaps one could modify it to use Environment Variables to set the proxy varaible.

Comment: The only problem with the dropbox method described in the link is that the **User** directory does not contain per package `*.sublime-settings`, thus these configurations being lost. Any way around this?

Comment: @RickyB Couldn't find any other way than symlinking each package `*.sublime-settings` file separately.

Comment: This basically proves my assumption. Thx. I don't need extra package settings, but only basic settings, which is the point.

Answer (score 17):

**IMPORTANT: My answer is not correct. Tomek's answer is better**

Before you start, close Sublime Text 3

1. Create a folder in Dropbox called `Sublime Text 3`
2. Move the following two folders to this folder.

   ```
   ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages

   ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Installed\ Packages
   ```
3. Create symlinks from their original location to their new locations in Dropbox:

   ```
   $ ln -s ~/Dropbox/App\ Settings/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Installed Packages ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Installed\ Packages

   $ ln -s ~/Dropbox/App\ Settings/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages
   ```
4. Open Sublime Text 3

Comment: The other answer is the correct one, if you are only using Package control packages, `To properly sync your installed packages across different machines, you actually do not want to sync the whole Packages/ and Installed Packages/ folders.`, `The proper solution is to sync only the Packages/User/ folder`. From https://sublime.wbond.net/docs/syncing

Comment: @KarthikT I've given Tomek the win.

Comment: Thanks, yours is the method I use, with git instead of dropbox, and a looot of files keep changing.. Your answer is more generic though, and works for non Package control packages

Answer (score 8):

**For Linux users using Dropbox**

---

The following is an excerpt taken directly from Sublime Text Package Control DOCS Syncing:

> The proper solution is to install Package Control on all machines and
>   then to sync only the Packages/User/ folder. This folder contains the
>   Package Control.sublime-settings file, which includes a list of all
>   installed packages. If this file is copied to another machine, the
>   next time Sublime Text is started, Package Control will install the
>   correct version of any missing packages.

This also sync your **preferences.sublime-settings** and your **macros**! Exactly what I wanted for Christmas.

---

**Instructions:**

If your Dropbox folder is not in the default location, you'll need to change ~/Dropbox to your location.

1) Close Sublime Text  ( Very important! )
2) Open Terminal

Obs: *for Sublime Text 2 just change 3 by 2*

**First Machine**

On your first machine, use the following instructions.

```
cd ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/
mkdir ~/Dropbox/Sublime
mv User ~/Dropbox/Sublime/
ln -s ~/Dropbox/Sublime/User
```

**Other Machine(s)**

On your other machine(s), use the following instructions. These instructions will remove your User/ folder and all contents!

```
cd ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/
rm -r User
ln -s ~/Dropbox/Sublime/User
```

---

ref: https://packagecontrol.io/docs/syncing#dropbox-linux

Comment: Just be careful that these instructions are for Linux only, they're slightly different for other OSes. The page linked to by Igor and Tomek has more info: https://sublime.wbond.net/docs/syncing