# Sublime Text - problems syncing via dropbox

Tags: synchronization, sublimetext3

I'm using portable Sublime Text at work (with package control). I need to use the portable version because the non-portable one is bunging up my roaming profile. I'm hoping to sync my settings across computers. I've followed online instructions carefully, but cannot get the sync to work. Here is my set up.

On Machine A (my home machine; Mac), the "User" folder in "/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages" is synced to Dropbox via a Symlink. The Symlink is inside "Sublime Text 3/Packages", while the actual folder is stored on Dropbox. Sublime Text works fine on this machine.

I have the same set up on Machine B (my work machine; Windows). I've created a symlink called "User" inside "E:\Sublime Text Build 3114\Packages", and this points to the folder on Dropbox.

However, when I open Sublime Text portable, none of the packages are updated.

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend using Git to sync your settings and packages! You have way more control. See [this article](https://medium.com/@devmount/using-git-to-sync-sublime-text-settings-f70b8dc7a40d#.6yue7ii3r) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29687417/is-there-a-way-to-sync-sublime-text-settings-across-multiple-computers).

Comment: Many thanks. I'll look into that. I'm comfortable with dropbox, and obviously there's a learning curve around git, but it appears to the go-to technology for this kind of thing.